# .NET 4.0 Project will not run on Windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a program that I am developing using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. I have my project setup to target Framework 4.0 and my platform target as x86. I can get it to build and run on my 64 bit, and on a Win 7 32 bit machine with .NET 4.0, but it will not run on XP.

I am using the BCL Portability Pack and Microsoft Async NuGet packages. I have already installed the KB2468871 update for .NET 4.0 on XP.

I have also run the Fusion data logger and received this:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (3/14/2014 @ 9:18:05 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  U:\All_Access\UserName\iBEdit\iBedit64Forms\bin\Release\IBEdit.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = USER
LOG: DisplayName = IBEdit.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///U:/All_Access/UserName/iBEdit/iBedit64Forms/bin/Release/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = IBEdit.exe
Calling assembly : IBEdit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: U:\All_Access\UserName\iBEdit\iBedit64Forms\bin\Release\IBEdit.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/All_Access/UserName/iBEdit/iBedit64Forms/bin/Release/en/IBEdit.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/All_Access/UserName/iBEdit/iBedit64Forms/bin/Release/en/IBEdit.resources/IBEdit.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/All_Access/UserName/iBEdit/iBedit64Forms/bin/Release/en/IBEdit.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/All_Access/UserName/iBEdit/iBedit64Forms/bin/Release/en/IBEdit.resources/IBEdit.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

There is no "en" folder in my project's "Release" folder. Could that be causing issues? Why is it looking there?

Are there any other changes I need to make to my project?

**Update:**

There is no Exception given, just the message: "iBEdit has encountered a problem and needs to close"

Here is the AppConfig code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SpecSrvSoapBinding"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://example.com/TCheckWebServices/services/SpecSrv" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SpecSrvSoapBinding" contract="DBService.SpecSrv" name="SpecSrv"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Update 2:**

Not really a success, but I have convinced management that trying to develop this app to work with XP is a waste and they should let me focus my efforts on upgrading our machines to Windows 7.

Comment: Does the XP box have SP3 ?

Comment: I don't understand what this LOG file is, what do you mean it "does not run" are you getting an exception? Will a .NET 4.0 "Hello World" run? Have you tried remotely debugging on the Windows XP box?

Comment: Yes, just got all of the latest updates on it yesterday.

Comment: XP support is getting 'retired' soon.  Best to move away from it if you can :)

Comment: @Alan if you have no idea what a fusion log is, maybe read some .net documentation?

Comment: @Alan
I do not get an exception (edited post), I have not tried remote debugging, how is that done?

Comment: What is your and the machines language? This loosks more like a resource / localization problem, if you decode the names of the files it fails to find.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy
Haha, my other job here is to migrate all the computers for my company to Win 7 (which is why I am making this app in C#); There's over 100 machines running proprietary VB6 coded software, it's not pretty.

Comment: Ok, it is running from network share. I'm assuming XP doesn't support this, but Win 7 does? I will try it locally and report back.

Comment: What does '64' stand for in 'iBedit64Forms' ? if it's 64 bit application, you won't be able to run it on XP which 32 bit only. But you should get a BadImageFormatException...

Comment: @Seb That was the project's old name. As I described before, I set it up to target x86 now and it is running on Win7 32 bit machine.

Comment: I'm sorry I read the question too fast. :-/

Comment: @Seb No problem, it was initially only supposed to run on 64 bit, but they needed support for 32, so I had to change it.

Comment: @TomTom The language for both computers is English US

Answer (score 3):

Something you attempting to load from your app.config is causing this.

Perhaps a file location in the app.config which does not exist in your XP machine.

Anyway, This does **not** look like .Net 4.0 support for XP issue.
It looks like it is coming from your code - and not from the .NET "envelope".

Sorry for the short answer,
But if you ain't going to show any related actual code - this is the best I can do.

Update (after seeing your config):

---> `<binding name="SpecSrvSoapBinding"/>` I think that this is what failing to load on the XP machine.

To validate on that - remark this part from the app.config and remark all the code that use that and than try and see if you get the same error again.

Comment: +1 I have had similar issues like this, the error reporting while attempting to load the `app.config` could use a great deal of improvement/specificity.

Comment: or may be show the content of app.config as you mentioned?

Comment: I can post the content of app.config, I will have it shortly.

Comment: @V-SHY app.config is posted

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to compile localized in english(en)? I found similar error in this question,hope can help u, 
[How can I modify my C# project file so that Resources.resx is compiled into the satellite assembly for my UICulture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657736/how-can-i-modify-my-c-sharp-project-file-so-that-resources-resx-is-compiled-into)

Your problem is MVS cannot find the **localized resource** for **en**.

> LOG: DisplayName = IBEdit.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture= **en** ,
>   PublicKeyToken=null  (Fully-specified)

Change Culture = **en** to Culture= **neutral** if possible. Sorry if I misleading you.

### Old

Do you have the four mentioned download URL files at other place of your windows? Put those file under your release folder as it mentioned and see what happened? It seem like cannot download those EXEs and DLLs for executing?

Comment: @user3232337 LOG: DisplayName = IBEdit.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture= **en** , PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified), the Culture is en here, I believe this is the cause of your problem

Comment: This confuses me because everywhere in my program, the culture is set to "neutral". The LOG file only says "en" when I run it on XP, but I don't know why. If I have any free time, I'll go back and look at it. Thanks for your findings.

Comment: Try to set these `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` to neutral by refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh(v%3Dvs.110).aspx

Comment: Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx, may be you need **invariant culture** An invariant culture is culture-insensitive. Your application specifies the invariant culture by name using an empty string ("") or by its identifier. InvariantCulturedefines an instance of the invariant culture. It is associated with the English language but not with any country/region. It is used in almost any method in theGlobalization namespace that requires a culture.

Comment: A neutral culture is a culture that is associated with a language but not with a country/region. A specific culture is a culture that is associated with a language and a country/region. For example, fr is the neutral name for the French culture, and fr-FR is the name of the specific French (France) culture. Note that Chinese (Simplified) and Chinese (Traditional) are also considered neutral cultures.

Comment: I might try switching them to en-US, just to see if that solves it.